# Why context parameter of getServerSideProps doesn't contain query params after consecutive calls

Tags: next.js

I am implementing a movie catalog using Next js. I want the catalog to be rendered on the server side, so I am using the `getServerSideProps(context)` function for that purpose. There is also search functionality, which is implemented by passing the 'search' query param in the URL (e.g. **https://<domain>?search=<search>**). I am getting the query param from the context passed to the above-mentioned function. The problem is that after first rendering consecutive calls to the function won't pass the query param (I checked it by `console.log`). I have spent the last 2 days searching for examples similar to my case without any success. I know that the first render and consecutive update using `router.push` are handled differently (one renders the HTML on the server side, and the other makes an API request and passes the result as props to the page). So in the second case, query params are not available. My question is whether this is expected behavior or not and what can I do to achieve the desired behavior?